# Unable to edit custom text items in Ext charts

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I have a chart made with Ext js.The chart has some custom text items. I would like to dynamically change these texts.I want these text components as part of svg because exported images of chart should also contains these custom texts.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zczP/40/)

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define("PopulationPoint", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: [ "state", "population" ]
    });
    var a = Ext.create("Ext.draw.Text", {
        type: "text",
        text: "Initial Text",
        font: "24px Arial",
        width: 500,
        height: 100,
        x: 20,
        y: 20
    });
    var b = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        model: "PopulationPoint",
        data: [ {
            state: "Alabama",
            population: 4802740
        }, {
            state: "Alaska",
            population: 722718
        }, {
            state: "Arizona",
            population: 6482505
        }, {
            state: "Arkansas",
            population: 2937979
        }, {
            state: "California",
            population: 37691912
        }, {
            state: "Colorado",
            population: 5116796
        }, {
            state: "Connecticut",
            population: 3580709
        }, {
            state: "Delaware",
            population: 907135
        }, {
            state: "DC",
            population: 617996
        } ]
    });
    Ext.create("Ext.chart.Chart", {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 470,
        height: 400,
        store: b,
        items: [ a ],
        series: [ {
            type: "pie",
            field: "population",
            label: {
                field: "state",
                display: "outside",
                font: "12px Arial"
            }
        } ]
    });
    setInterval(function() {  
        a.setText("NewText"); // This statement has no use
    }, 3e3);
 });
```

Anybody knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

It worked when I used `Ext.draw.Sprite` instead of `Ext.draw.Text`. But still exported image of chart contains the old text. Updated [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zczP/42/)

```
var txtDraw =  Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
    type:'text',
    text  : 'Initial Text',
    font  : '24px Arial',
    width : 500,
    height: 100, 
    x:20,
    y:20
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txtDraw.setAttributes({ 'text':'Jeff'},true )`

use setAttributes method of Ext.draw.Sprite

reference - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite-method-setAttributes

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a bug because although `setText` method shows a sensible code:

```
setText: function(text) {
    var me = this,
        surface,
        sprite;

    if (me.rendered) {
        surface = me.surface;
        sprite = surface.items.items[0];

        me.text = text || '';
        surface.remove(sprite);
        me.textConfig.type = 'text';
        me.textConfig.text = me.text;
        sprite = surface.add(me.textConfig);
        sprite.setAttributes({
            rotate: {
                degrees: me.degrees
            }
        }, true);
        if (me.autoSize || me.viewBox) {
            me.updateLayout();
        }
    } else {
        me.on({
            render: function() {
                me.setText(text);
            },
            single: true
        });
    }
}
```

the problem is the text sprite is never rendered, `me.rendered` stays false so the code is never executed. A very dirty workaround would be to set rendered flag from outside.

Comment: Thanks for the response Saki. Your observation is right. But I could fix the issue by using `Ext.draw.Sprite` .

Comment: But still i am unable to download the chart with updated text. Can you please help me with this?